# freqpoly ignore certain legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data size is huge and the only way I knew to check all of the variables in a column was using  `sapply` or  `str()`, both of which returned 55 states. The plot however shows only 8 states.

I haven't heard anywhere that R removes extra legends for convenience.. Could anyone let me know what seems to be an issue? Thanks in advance.

```
brfss2013_temp <- brfss2013 %>% 
  select(misnervs, mishopls, misdeprd, misrstls, miseffrt, miswtles, employ1, X_state) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(misnervs), !is.na(mishopls), !is.na(misdeprd), !is.na(misrstls), 
         !is.na(miseffrt), !is.na(miswtles), as.numeric(misnervs) <= 5, 
         as.numeric(mishopls) <= 5, as.numeric(misdeprd) <= 5, as.numeric(misrstls) <= 5, 
         as.numeric(miseffrt) <= 5, as.numeric(miswtles) <= 5)

brfss2013_temp$misnervs <- as.numeric(brfss2013_temp$misnervs)
brfss2013_temp$mishopls <- as.numeric(brfss2013_temp$mishopls)
brfss2013_temp$misdeprd <- as.numeric(brfss2013_temp$misdeprd)
brfss2013_temp$misrstls <- as.numeric(brfss2013_temp$misrstls)
brfss2013_temp$miseffrt <- as.numeric(brfss2013_temp$miseffrt)
brfss2013_temp$miswtles <- as.numeric(brfss2013_temp$miswtles)
brfss2013_temp$misrep <- rowMeans(brfss2013_temp[1:6])
sapply(brfss2013_temp, levels)

ggplot(data = brfss2013_temp, 
       mapping = aes(x = misrep, colour = X_state)) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 0.2) + 
  labs(x = 'frequency of feeling negative in recent month, 1(all) - 5(none)', 
       colour = 'state')

ggplot(data = brfss2013_temp, 
       mapping = aes(x = misrep, colour = employ1)) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 0.2) + 
  labs(x = 'frequency of feeling negative in recent month, 1(all) - 5(none)', 
       colour = 'employment type')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the original dataset—it could be that the state is encoded as a factor with levels for each state, and some of those states are simply not present in the data. Can you post a link to the original data set, in order to make this reproducible?

Comment: If you want to test this, you can type the following on R: load("brfss2013.RData")
I actually don't know what you mean by giving links to a data set. This was the only way I knew how to process the data in the first place.

Comment: Is `brfss2013.RData` a file that someone supplied you, or that you saved yourself? Without a copy of this file, we can't reproduce your analysis :)

Comment: I should think it was one of the open-sourced data available on R. I don't really know how R library networks work.. but it seems to load certain data just fine, without downloading anything extra. All I did was install Rstudio and loaded the data. So no.. I wasn't given.

Comment: I've found a few tutorials that load that dataset this way, but as far as I can tell, it isn't present on my installation. I'm not sure if those tutorials were made for an old version of R, but usually if a package provides access to a dataset, you load it using the `data()` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not much I can do without the source dataset :/

Comment: I am so sorry to waste your time and space here. I knew my R was installed to the newest version so I checked again, and found the [link](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_384b2d9eda4b29131fb681b243a7767d_brfss2013.RData?Expires=1514937600&Signature=aAVCwKtDbAZ30mAIzo1ZHau1VWU7~Ujd763jRfwb9Q3QPdgVIbQNbefhQH0TSxeuCRnir~qKaF1k6TY-15l6FUIzkRD7MuUQxWK-9KdF4AE5IUi6TbUBFr2E47FNDsX7h2yRFxI1zKN1geXu4uqvZWHf3dkHT-OlaeK6a971DPA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A). Does this work??

Comment: Also found a [link](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_e34476fda339107329fc316d1f98e042_brfss_codebook.html?Expires=1514937600&Signature=DvSMK10QMI87DmwMnPMpUgTI0FlvDy8d4VllYQgrGUCShspoJc3NNjtvxTJf9GtGstHWUGLt7IE8CKE27EzMiPa-klO-AQkZHR6Zp5116h8mdJho5yvfLrHi5iSpX1mnzhF8fvXlDGyMXVlMBoL-RcNPygJUb~JxT69Snk07PTM_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A) explaining the variables..I should have known this earlier -_-;

Comment: That's okay! Thanks for doing the leg work :) I'm going to sleep now (Aussie time), but I'll take a look in the morning (if someone else doesn't get there first).

Comment: Try generating this table: `table(brfss2013_temp$X_state)`. It shows that your `brfss2013_temp` dataset has observations only for the following US states:    `Alabama         Maine Massachusetts     Minnesota        Nevada     Tennessee    Washington`